# How to call Google Cloud Build from a Python script

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

How do I call Google Cloud Build from a Python script? I keep seeing the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import codecs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 96
    *, _is_text_encoding=None):
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

The python code is simply:

```
    subprocess.call(["./CloudBuild.sh", signedURL])
```

The CloudBuild.sh script is simply:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    signedURL=$1

    gcloud builds submit --config='Dockerfiles/cloudbuild.yaml' --substitutions=_SIGNED_URL=$signedURL 'Dockerfiles'`
```

The same error occurred with Python3.6 so I upgraded to 3.7, but no luck.

The script CloudBuild.sh works if I run it from the command line. It also works from Python if I just put test code in it such as `ls` command. It only fails when calling `gcloud builds submit`.
The same error occurs if I call gcloud directly from `subprocess.call()` in Python.